# iTunes Connect will not invite my admin internal tester

Tags: ios, itunes, testflight

I uploaded a binary with entitlement beta-reports-active:true. I went to Internal Testers, chose the checkbox for an admin internal tester whose account was in iTunes Connect about a year, and clicked the Invite button. The button changed to Invited, but the admin's status stayed blank, and they never got an invite email. I then deleted the admin's iTunes Connect account, again invited them to be an admin, got them to again accept, made them an internal tester, and tried to Invite them. I still got nothing when I try to invite them to test internally.

I later succeeded in inviting a different admin who unfortunately will not be testing this app, and whose admin account has been in iTunes Connect about a year like the first admin. So it's not the app.

But when I created a new 3rd admin account, iTunes Connect failed to invite them either - blank status and no email when I hit Invite.